# Make sure Java will not close OutputStream before PrinWriter.print() finishes

Tags: java, sockets, outputstream

I'm developing a distributed system that receives requests via Socket and writes the results back using OutputStream.

I'm facing problems because I have to return a very large string, but Java just keeps the execution of the code after I call the method print() without it finished printing:

```
public void attendRequisition(Socket clientSocket) {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

    pw.print(getResults());

    pw.close()
}
```

Some information:

- I **need** to close the connection after sending the results.
- Without the close() instruction, the whole printing process takes about 3~5 seconds to finishes
- I'm using telnet to test this method, and I can see the message coming and being cut becase of Java running the close() instruction
- I **can't** count with receiving client's feedback

I believe this is happening because Java thinks the method print() finished executing, but what might be happening is that Java sends the message to the JVM, and JVM send it to the network adapter, and since the message is very large, close() method is called before the network adapter is able to send the entire message.

What I need is a way to make sure Java will only run the instruction close() after the printing process finished and the client received the entire message.

**UPDATE**: I was able to get it working properly by adding a `Thread.sleep()`. By doing this, the SO has enough time to send the message before Java closes the connection. But I don't want to use this solution, it implicates on too many problems.

Comment: 'I'm facing problems' is not a problem description, and the part after 'because of' is just guesswork. Are you sure the message is really as long as you think?

Comment: "message is very large". How large? Some commercial software vendors have a maximum packet size such that no single packet is larger than about 2k. I suspect that the iterative nature of those algorithms might preclude the type of error you are seeing.

Comment: And 'Java just keeps the execution of the code after I call the method print() without it finished printing' is meaningless.

Comment: By 'I'm facing problems' I meant I'm not able to send the entire message to the client part.

Comment: "message is very large": it has 351 KB

Comment: And by 'Java just keeps the execution of the code after I call the method print() without it finished printing' I mean I THINK Java sends the message to the SO and concludes its execution is done, but the SO still sending it, but befor the SO is able to send the whole message, Java has already executed the close method, which runs much faster than sending a 351 kB message over the network.

Comment: But you don't know that. All you know is the message got truncated. If you knew why, you wouldn't be posting. Your assertions about it being due to a premature close are not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using `DataOutputStream.writeBytes()`. This way, the execution only continues when the method finishes sending the data. It is slower, but works.

Answer (score -1):

I'll bet that if you use another constructor (i.e., the one whose 2nd argument is a boolean to indicate your desire to flush) then your example will work. The way you're constructing the object, autoflush is disabled.

If your real code is more complex, then you can call pw.flush() at the appropriate moments.

Comment: Closing causes flushing.

Comment: That's what the docs say but how do you know you haven't found an edge case that might motivate you to log a java bug? If you have to know "the client received the entire message", then the client must send you back a response. There is absolutely no other way to know the client received the message.

Comment: You know because `PrintWriter` has been working for 20 years, and if there's a close bug why not an autoflush bug? This type of thinking is unproductive. It is 99.999% certain that the bug is in the OP's code, and you shouldn't encourage him to think otherwise.

Comment: @EJP I know that. But he mentioned large messages? Surely that puts him closer to the edge. Right?

Comment: No, why? It's just a standard copy loop, it just runs as many times as it needs to.

Comment: Yes, which would necessarily be a larger number of times than a smaller string. Hence more instructions executed somewhere in the stack. It's up to the OP to find the cause. That means he'll have to introduce changes to his code to find it. I think I suggested a change.

Comment: Oh come off it. He has a bug in his code, and he needs to find *that*. Do you seriously think the Java guys don't test printing large strings? And  if there's an edge case, how exactly will your suggested change magically bypass this alleged non-existent bug? You're not even making sense.

Comment: Hmm. You said "PrintWriter swallows exceptions" and yet you chastise me for helping someone determine if a handled exception is the cause of his problem. You need to chill out.

Answer (score -1):

> I can see the message coming and being cut becase of Java running the close() instruction

No you can't. You can see the message being cut, unless you're wrong about how long it is, but you're jumping to conclusions about the reason. Java does not close the `PrintWriter` before it has finished sending. It flushes the writer to the socket send buffer, blocking if necessary, and then closes the underlying socket, which buffers a FIN behind the data. All the data gets sent, and all the data gets received, before the FIN arrives, which signals end of stream to the receiver.

Possibly you are unaware that `PrintWriter` swallows exceptions and therefore should really not be used over a network.

Comment: Yes, I do can see the message being written on telnet terminal. And yes, I do know `PrintWriter` swallows exeptions, this is exacly why (not only, of course) that I'm using `PrintWriter`, so I don't have to worry about handling too much exceptions.

Comment: So you don't know whether an exception was thrown, so you can't rule it out. So *rule* it out, by using `BufferedWriter.write()` for example, and then see whether you still have a problem.